# Confuse display data from database

Tags: php, mysql

i want to display data from database. i want to display 4 tables named 'score', 'listening_score', 'reading_score' and 'structure_score'. 'score' table contained final score.

index.php

```
<? php
   echo "Your TOEFL Score, <br>";
         echo "<table class=\"score\">";
         $email = $_SESSION['email'];
         $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM score where email='$email'");
         $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM structure_score where email='$email'");
         $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listening_score where email='$email'");
         $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reading_score where email='$email'");
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
            echo "
               <h3> <span >".$row['Score']."</span> </h3>";

         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "
               <tr><td>Score Structure: </td> <td>".$row['Score']."</td><td>Right Answer: </td> <td>".$row['Right_Answer']."</td></tr>";   

         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
            echo "
               <tr><td>Score Listening: </td> <td>".$row['Score']."</td><td>Right Answer: </td> <td>".$row['Right_Answer']."</td></tr>";

         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
            echo "
               <tr><td>Score Reading: </td> <td>".$row['Score']."</td><td>Right Answer: </td> <td>".$row['Right_Answer']."</td></tr>";
               }
             }
           }
         }
        echo "</table><br><br>";
?>
```

i want to display:

```
233
Score Structure:    24  Right Answer:   0
Score Listening:    24  Right Answer:   0
Score Reading:   22 Right Answer:   0
```

BUT when i test twice, data will be displaying like this:

```
233

263
Score Structure:    24  Right Answer:   0
Score Listening:    24  Right Answer:   0
Score Reading:  22  Right Answer:   0

Score Reading:  31  Right Answer:   12
Score Listening:    33  Right Answer:   10
Score Structure:    32  Right Answer:   8
```

I want to display like this:

```
233
Score Structure:    24  Right Answer:   0
Score Listening:    24  Right Answer:   0
Score Reading:  22  Right Answer:   0

263
Score Reading:  31  Right Answer:   12
Score Listening:    33  Right Answer:   10
Score Structure:    32  Right Answer:   8
```

this is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `score` (
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Score` int(100) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listening_score` (
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Right_Answer` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `Score` int(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reading_score` (
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Right_Answer` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `Score` int(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `structure_score` (
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Right_Answer` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `Score` int(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the tables you are using? for us to be able to understand more of your problem

Comment: yes, I'm sure many users can help you, but without more details, we can't

Comment: So there can be multiple TOEFL scores associated to the same email? That doesn't really make sense, it seems you are missing a notion of "session" or something - so an email has a score from session 1 (which happened at date X) and a score for session 2 (which happened at date Y). Otherwise you cannot group the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What u show in PHP code is to make circle in circle no wonder it will go out to be like ABCDDCB nesting.
From the tables you built, I can see no relation between the four tables but for the `email` field. I suggest u to add `total_score` field in the tables except for `score` table. And select sentences constrain to the unique one with `email` and `total_score`.
Code like following:

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82BNq.png)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7IQp.png)